# How do I limit the number of records per tab when exporting to Excel?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report in Crystal Reports 2013 with a requirement that the maximum row count per tab is 100,000 when exported to Excel. How do I accomplish this?

Most articles demonstrate how to limit the number of records per group, which would begin a new page, but my record count exceeds the number of pages.

I followed the instructions on this page, but the report exported to a single Excel tab.
https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/23/grouping-on-n-a-certain-number-of-records-per-group/

```
whilereadingrecords;
numbervar r; numbervar g;
if remainder(r, 100000) = 0
then (r := r + 1; g := g + 1;)
else (r := r + 1; g;)
```

I expected the export to produce a multi-tab file with 100,000 records per tab, but the export produced a single-tab file with 600,000+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rowcounter ( your formula can be used  for this) you can create a group based on rowcounter values and use bursting to export each group to a separate worksheet as it is shown in this post http://r-tag.com/Pages/BlogPost/1

However, using Crystal reports to export 600k records to Excel is probably not the best approach. The report will retrieve the data, then render it based on your printer settings and will prepare pages and then the data will be exported. Rendering might be really slow and it is not required at all. It will be way easier and faster if you export the data directly using a SQL and generate Excel file. What is your database ?   Here is a sample how to export data to Excel for SQL :
https://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/export-to-excel-xlsx-file-with-openrowset/

You will need to put the command in a cursor and export 100k records on each turn